# The cypher PROFILE keyword asks for a transaction even if there is already one

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to profile the following query on the neo4j server console (community edition, version 1.9.2):

```
PROFILE START ungrouped=node(1) 
CREATE (grouped{__type__:'my.package.Grouped'})<-[:HAS_NEXT]-(ungrouped) 
MATCH (ungrouped)-[:LEAF]->(leaf) 
WITH leaf.`custom-GROUP` as groupValue, grouped, leaf
CREATE UNIQUE (grouped)-[:GROUP]->({__type__:'my.package.Group',groupKey:'GROUP',groupValue:groupValue,groupOrigin:ID(ungrouped)})-[:LEAF]->(leaf) 
RETURN DISTINCT grouped;
```

When I run the above query, I get the message

```
==> I need a transaction!
```

Ok, so I created one with

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
==> Transaction started
```

Afterwards I run the same query again. But unfortunately I get the same message again:

```
==> I need a transaction!
```

But there definitely is a transaction. When I type

```
ROLLBACK
```

the transaction is successfully rolled back:

```
==> Transaction rolled back
```

Am I doing something wrong? Does profiling not work for such kind of a query by design? Or is this simply a bug in neo4j?

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: I am running the neo4j server community version 1.9.2

Comment: Just tried this, works fine over here in neo4j-shell with 1.9.2: `neo4j-sh (0)$ BEGIN TRANSACTION
Transaction started
neo4j-sh (0)$ PROFILE CREATE n;
+--------------------------------------------+
| No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
+--------------------------------------------+

EmptyResult(_rows=0, _db_hits=0)
UpdateGraph(commands=["CreateNode(n,Map())"], _rows=1, _db_hits=1)
  StartTransaction(_rows=1, _db_hits=0)
    ParameterPipe(_rows=1, _db_hits=0)
neo4j-sh (0)$ ROLLBACK
Transaction rolled back
neo4j-sh (0)$ 
`

Comment: Can you recreate this with an empty database and the neo4j-shell?

Comment: When I execute my query on an empty database everything works fine without asking for a transaction a second time. But when I have data imported that is matched by my query I get the mentioned behaviour.